# Finding the Largest and Smallest Number using Ternary Operators

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain how to find the largest and smallest number using ternary operators? I know how it works (`?` and `:`) but only if the given is 2 inputs, if its more than two my brain explodes. This is a reference code on how they did it to find the largest number on 5 inputs. Can someone please explain?

[image: Finding the Largest Number in 5 inputs using Ternary Operators]

I'm sorry, here is the code in  the image:

int n1 = 5, n2 = 6, n3 = 7, n4 = 8, n5 = 9;

Console.WriteLine("Largest = {0}", ((n1 > n2 ? n1 > n3 ? n1 : n3 : n2 > n3 ? n2 : n3) > (n4 > n5 ? n4 : n5) ? (n1 > n2 ? n1 > n3 ? n1 : n3 : n2 > n3 ? n2 : n3) : (n4 > n5 ? n4 : n5)));

I know its a shitty way to find the largest number, but can someone make it find six inputs...Please!

Comment: Please paste the code in the image into your post.

Comment: The conditional operator has three parts: a boolean expression and two other expressions, only one of which will be evaluated depending on the result of the condition. So nothing is stopping you from using a conditional expression for _each_ of those two expressions. In other words, nesting your conditional. That said, highly-nested conditionals are difficult to follow, as you alluded to. Here it's worse because it relies on operator precedence. There is no performance benefit from writing code like this. The only thing it does is make the code more compact and less readable/maintainable.

Comment: One time I checked in something that looked like this just to see if people were paying attention in code reviews.

Comment: The output from one ternary operator can be the input for another, and the output from that ternary operator can be the input for another and so on. Just as you can chain as many function calls as you want, you can also chain as many ternary operators as you want. You generally should do so because the code gets hard to read but, if you do, make sure to break it over multiple lines and use appropriate indenting to make it clearer. I would copy your code into an answer and format it properly but I can't because you have poste3d a picture instead of text. Do you get it now?

Answer (score -2):

This is just pseudocode , but try this :

`min = a<b ? (a<c ? a : c) : (b<c ? b : c);`

From:

> https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-a-C-program-to-find-the-smallest-number-among-3-given-using-a-conditional-operator

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-the-largest-number-using-ternary-operator/

Comment: Yah, thanks to that. But how do you construct a condition when its 3 to up just like in this code / int n1 = 5, n2 = 6, n3 = 7, n4 = 8, n5 = 9;
Console.WriteLine("Largest = {0}", ((n1 > n2 ? n1 > n3 ? n1 : n3 : n2 > n3 ? n2 : n3) > (n4 > n5 ? n4 : n5) ? (n1 > n2 ? n1 > n3 ? n1 : n3 : n2 > n3 ? n2 : n3) : (n4 > n5 ? n4 : n5))); /